# Clicar em Section e abrir DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quero que ao clicar na **Aba** da Section troque a classe da div que contem o atributo para mostrar. Ela está originalmente com uma classe que faz com que ela fique oculta.Tenho a função js ali mas não está funcionando

Quem conseguir ajudar agradeço. Espero que tenha ficado bom o post

```js
  var div = document.querySelector('div#minhaDiv');
    var section = document.querySelector('section#secao');
    section.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var aberto = div.classList.contains('teste');
        div.classList.toggle('teste2');
        this.innerHTML = aberto ? 'teste2' : 'teste';
```

```css
.teste{
  display: none;
}
.teste2{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste" id="minhaDiv">
  Filtro busca2:
  <select name="" onchange="" id="">
      <option value="0">...</option>
      <option value="1">Prazo decrescente</option>
      <option value="2">Prazo crescente</option>
      <option value="3">Título A - Z</option>
      <option value="4">Título Z - A</option>
  </select>
</div>


<section id = "secao" onclick = "">
  <p class="title" data-section-title>
    <a href="#">Tarefas Cadastradas</a>
  </p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <table class="responsive" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th width="15%">A Tarefa</th>
          <th width="15%">Funcionário</th>
          <th width="15%">Setor</th>
          <th width="5%">Status</th>
                      <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Prazo</th>
          <th width="10%">Nível Urgência</th>
          <th width="10%">Dia Fechamento</th>
          <th width="7%" style="text-align:center;">Editar</th>
          <th width="7%" style="text-align:center;">Excluir</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara seu código está funcionando, mas parece que está faltando é alguma Tags, e caracteres no código... Olha ai, quando vc clica na `Secao` aparece o `select` e faz o `innerHTML` certinho

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div#minhaDiv');
var section = document.querySelector('section#secao');

section.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var aberto = div.classList.contains('teste');
    div.classList.toggle('teste2');
    this.innerHTML = aberto ? 'teste2' : 'teste';
})
```

```css
.teste {
    display: none;
}

.teste2 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="teste" id="minhaDiv">
    Filtro busca2:
    <select name="" onchange="" id="">
        <option value="0">...</option>
        <option value="1">Prazo decrescente</option>
        <option value="2">Prazo crescente</option>
        <option value="3">Título A - Z</option>
        <option value="4">Título Z - A</option>
    </select>
</div>


<section id="secao" onclick="">
    <p class="title" data-section-title>
        <a href="#">Tarefas Cadastradas</a>
    </p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
        <table class="responsive" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="15%">A Tarefa</th>
                    <th width="15%">Funcionário</th>
                    <th width="15%">Setor</th>
                    <th width="5%">Status</th>
                    <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Prazo</th>
                    <th width="10%">Nível Urgência</th>
                    <th width="10%">Dia Fechamento</th>
                    <th width="7%" style="text-align:center;">Editar</th>
                    <th width="7%" style="text-align:center;">Excluir</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Foi na hora de colar que coloquei um `tbody` a mais ali. Não sei o que está acontecendo então deve ser algo no resto do script obrigado pela atenção

Comment: @LucasMachado sem problemas meu caro, se resolveu é o que importa rss []´s

Comment: Ainda não estava funcionando mas colocando o javascript dentro de um `window.onload()` funcionou.

Comment: @LucasMachado a sim, seria uma boa pratica mesmo, que bom que deu certo ai :)